# Two Categories collapse to 1 row

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have two rows like so:

[image]

I would like to write a SQL query to collapse the two rows into one like this:

[image]

Does anyone have ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What is the criteria for joining rows -- same first 5 columns? Will there always be two rows (no more, no less) with such a match?

Comment: there will be either 1 or two rows but never more than two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
SELECT
  first_name,
  last_name,
  business_name,
  trade,
  date_submit,
  MAX(CASE WHEN insurer = 'Progressive' THEN status END) as status_progressive,
  MAX(CASE WHEN insurer = 'Travelers' THEN status END) as status_travelers
FROM table
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, business_name, trade, date_submit
```

I didn't test it, but that should give you the concept. There is nothing here that is unique to Amazon Redshift.